# Order by DESC query loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been trying for hours to order this Wordpress loop by DESC rather than ASC, what am I doing wrong?

```
function list_articles($query_arg){

    $articles_list = new WP_Query( $query_arg );

    if ( $articles_list->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<ul class="articles">';
        while ( $articles_list->have_posts() ) :
            $articles_list->the_post(array('order' => 'DESC'));
            get_template_part("template-parts/article-for-widget");
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    else :
        ?>
        <p><?php _e('No Articles Found!', 'framework'); ?></p>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: How are you working with your `list_articles` function parameter? Also `the_post()` doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: Here is the list article function works:  list_articles(array(
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                            'cat' => $cat_obj->term_id,
                                            'posts_per_page' => $number_of_cat_articles,
                                            'category_not_in' => $categories_not_in
                                        ));

Comment: `This function does not accept any parameters.`  - [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)

Comment: if you are passing `order desc` in function than remove from `the_post` , however `the_post` doesn't accept any parameter

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

`$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );`

For details :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Still need to pass $query_arg in the WP_Query, how can I add both in?

Comment: in which format your `$query_arg` is ? mean you are passing in array or string ?

Comment: $query_arg is an array

Comment: then you can use `array_merge` or $query_arg + $order_array, where order array is the array above.

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is of course a SQL query word. In your code the query in question has already been issued by the time you are trying (unsuccessfully) to pass along `DESC.` So there's no way it could work even if `the_post()` accepted parameters, which it does not.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

You need to say `DESC` before the query is issued by WordPress to MySQL.

This is how to do that, I believe. But you'll need to debug it, because $query_arg's format is a little unpredictable.

```
$query_arg['order'] = 'DESC';
$articles_list = new WP_Query( $query_arg );
if ( $articles_list->have_posts() ) :
   etc etc etc
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick, on var_dump I get the following: array(4) { ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" ["cat"]=> int(3) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(4) ["category_not_in"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: @user1955643 Tried removing parameter from `the_post`?

Comment: Ye I removed it, doesn't do anything.